# Image link does not work when parts are retrieved from API

Tags: python, django

I write a project of a list of films with their details(IMDB). When I click on the image of a film he doesn't go to the page of that film. I do not understand where the problem is in url on html file or in the models?

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/movies/%7B$%20url%20'movies:movie_detail'%20movie.slug%20%25%7D
Using the URLconf defined in django_movie_center.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
movies/ [name='movie_list']
movies/ category/<str:category> [name='movie_category']
movies/ language/<str:lang> [name='movie_language']
movies/ search/ [name='movie_search']
movies/ <slug:slug> [name='movie_detail']
movies/ year/<int:year> [name='movie_year']
^static/(?P<path>.*)$
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, movies/{$ url 'movies:movie_detail' movie.slug %}, didn't match any of these.
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify
# Create your models here.

CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('action','ACTION'),
    ('drama','DRAMA'),
    ('comedy','COMEDY'),
    ('romance','ROMANCE'),
)

LANGUAGE_CHOICES = (
    ('english','ENGLISH'),
    ('german','GERMAN'),
    ('hebrew','HEBREW')
)

STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('RA' , 'RECRNTLY ADDED'),
    ('MW' , 'MOST WATCHED'),
    ('TR' , 'TOP RATED'),
)

class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='movies')
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES , max_length=10)
    language = models.CharField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, max_length=10)
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, max_length=2)
    cast = models.CharField( max_length=100)
    year_of_production = models.DateField()
    views_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    movie_trailer = models.URLField()
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)



    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Movie, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

LINK_CHOICES = (
    ('D','DOWNLOAD LINK'),
    ('W','WATCH LINK'),
)

class MovieLink(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, related_name='movie_watch_link', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.CharField(choices=LINK_CHOICES , max_length=1)
    link = models.URLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.movie
```

app_url:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import MovieList , MovieDetail , Movie_Category , Movie_Language , Movie_Serch , Movie_Year
app_name = 'movie center'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', MovieList.as_view() , name='movie_list'),
    path('category/<str:category>', Movie_Category.as_view() , name='movie_category'),
    path('language/<str:lang>', Movie_Language.as_view() , name='movie_language'),
    path('search/', Movie_Serch.as_view() , name='movie_search'),
    path('<slug:slug>', MovieDetail.as_view() , name='movie_detail'),
    path('year/<int:year>', Movie_Year.as_view() , name='movie_year'),
```

The error is in `class="movies"` in
html_list_of_the_project:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body %}
        <main class="content">
            <section class="centered">
                {% if movie_category %}
                    <h3>{{movie_category|title}} Movies</h3>
                {% endif %}

                {% if movie_language %}
                    <h3>{{movie_language|title}} </h3>
                {% endif %}

                <div class="movies">
                    {% for movie in object_list %}
                        <div class="mov">
                        <a href="{$ url 'movies:movie_detail' movie.slug %}">
                            <img src="{{movie.image.url}}">
                            <h2 class="movietitle">{{movie.title}}</h2>
                        </a>
                        </div>
                    {% empty %}
                        <h3>This Category Is Empty !</h3>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
                {% if is_paginated %}
                  <nav class="pagination">
                    <ul>
                        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                           <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Prev</a></li>
                        {% else %}
                           <li class="disabled"></li>
                        {% endif %}

                        {% for pages in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
                          {% if page_obj.number == pages %}
                            <li><a href="#">{{pages}}</a> </li>
                          {% else %}
                            <li><a href="?page={{pages}}">{{pages}}</a> </li>
                          {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}

                        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                            <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a></li>
                        {% else %}
                           <li class="disabled"></li>
                        {% endif %}
                    </ul>
                  </nav>
                {% endif %}
            </section>

        </main>
{% endblock body %}
```

Comment: you have a $ in url... {$ url 'movies:movie_detail' movie.slug %} replace it to %...

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo "*$*" in the URL mentioned on the a-tag written in the movie for-loop

> ```
>  <a href="{$ url 'movies:movie_detail' movie.slug %}">
>                <img src="{{movie.image.url}}">
> ```

The URL should be like this: `{% url 'movies:movie_detail' movie.slug %}`